# Display flicker on movies, websites, animation on Ubuntu 13.10 / nVidia restricted driver

Tags: nvidia, display

I have been running **Ubuntu 12.10** (Linux **Mint 14**) with the proprietary `NVIDIA-updates` driver without any problems (I don't know the version from that repository by heart)

Recently, I installed **Ubuntu 13.10** (Linux **Mint 16**) and activated the `NVIDIA-319-updates` driver.

Now it turns out that my screen is flickering (constantly, as opposed to similar questions) during certain tasks.

- Watching a movie using the default movie player
- Watching videos on Youtube
- Zooming in/out on Google Maps

  - In all browsers
  - But NOT scrolling the map
- Entering/leaving folders in Nemo/Nautilus

The flicker is like watching interlaced video footage with the fields reversed. Or like something is double buffered but the buffers are displayed in the wrong order.

Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

First, `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings` because it isn't installed by default anymore. Then start it from the terminal, because it isn't added to the application menu anymore. Then **disable** *flipping*, whatever that is.

[image: nvidia-settings - disable "flipping"]

The fix works immediately when you remove the check from the box, no need to reboot.

Comment: Same exact problem, same exact fix worked. Except now the parts of the screen that used to flicker just don't update.